# why does my jQuery function stop running at "else if" after I add a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to build a sort of copy of the fullPage.js plugin effect, except what mine does is play with the height of each of my "slides" instead of their positioning. My function runs alright the first time around at "if", but once it gets to the "else if" it stops running. Can anyone shed some light on why this is doing that?

```
if (currentSlide == 1) {

$("#slide-1").addClass("next-slide");
isAnimating = true;

setTimeout(function(){
  isAnimating = false;
  currentSlide++;
  console.log(currentSlide);
  console.log(isAnimating);
}, 900)

} else if ((currentSlide == 2) && (isAnimating)) {

alert();
$("#slide-2").addClass("next-slide");
currentSlide++;
console.log('Current slide is: ' + currentSlide);

}
```

Comment: This looks like quirky architecture, when are you running this code? Could you post a bigger context, perhaps a codepen?

Comment: I would bet the `isAnimating` condition in the else if is the problem. You've clearly set it to false on slide 1. Granted we don't have any more context to see what else is happening.

Comment: https://codepen.io/alexyap/pen/KqvGWz?editors=0011 sorry about that i forgot to add in my codepen, anyway the purpose for the isAnimating variable is i want slide-1 to slide up without it being interrupted by slide-2, because without it slide-2 slides up even while slide-1 is still animating (sliding up)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code in your example, it looks like `currentSlide == 2 && isAnimating` will never be true after the callback function executes, so if the callback function executes before the function that this logic block lives in executes, then the code inside the `else if` will not execute.